# why does we need to build a boost library ,isn't it sufficient to just include the head files ,as boost are template

Tags: c++, boost

I am sorry if this is a naive question , I just wondered why there is need to build boost library,as
use the bootstrap file in the boost library package and build a library which contains .lib .dll the static and dynamic library.As to my knowledge , boost is a template library , there is no sense to build a binary library , you can just include the header file and use it directly ...

Comment: It depends on which part of boost you are using.  Some require compiled libs, others are header-only.  Maybe you're using a part of the library that is header-only.

Comment: thank you , now cleared , this is indeed a toddler question.

Comment: @wangz I would not call it a toddler question. Boost does have a (partially inaccurate) reputation for being header-only, so it is reasonable to wonder why there is a compiled component. I was surprised when I did not find a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Boost question, the Boost website is a good place for answers, specifically the "header only libraries" section appearing in both [getting started on Unix varients](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries) and [getting started on Windows](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries).

> **Nothing to Build?**
>
> Most Boost libraries are header-only: they consist entirely of header files containing templates and inline functions, and require no separately-compiled library binaries or special treatment when linking.

Note that "most" is used, not "all". In version 1.71, there are 16 libraries that must be built separately and 7 libraries that have optional separately-compiled components. (The Boost site has a list of these libraries, and that list gets updated as new versions are released.) If you're not using these particular libraries, then right, you can just include headers without linking to a Boost library.